# result of "less than" operator in bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do a script which downloads a file and if it takes less than 'x' seconds it's a pass but from some reason I can't get it to work properly, i've tried '<=' '-lt' in the below example it's always 'FAST' i'e 2.09 FAST

```
#!/bin/bash

file=&(time -p wget -O /dev/null -q http://site/file.iso ) 2>&1 | grep real | sed -e s/real//g -e s/' '//g

if [ $file <= 1 ]
then
    echo "FAST"
else
    echo "SLOW"
fi
```

Comment: `file=&(time etc...` should be `file=$(time etc...`

Comment: Damn fat fingers, replaced £ with $ but still doesn't work, think my brackets are in the wrong place. I tried    "file=$(time -p wget -O /dev/null -q http://site/file.ios 2>&1 | grep real | sed -e s/real//g -e s/' '//g) but it outputs real 2.47
user 0.01
sys 0.06
PASS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture the output of `time` you need curly braces:

```
file=$( { time -p wget -O /dev/null -q http://site/file.iso ; } 2>&1 | grep real | sed -e s/real//g -e s/' '//g )
```

Bash can't do floating-point calculations, so you can use `bc` for that:

```
[[ $( echo $file' <= 1.0' | bc ) == 1 ]] && echo FAST || echo SLOW
```

Comment: Why would curly braces change capturing that output?

Comment: Because you want the `2>&1` to apply to output of `time`, not to the output of the command `time` is running. If you run without the braces, the `time` output does not go into the pipe and the `file` variable does not get set to what's desired.

Comment: I wouldn't post it if I didn't try it, and yes, it works perfectly. Did you try it?

Comment: I did, clearly incorrectly the first time. I have no idea what is going on here. bash is *clearly* handling this differently than the simple case. I wonder why. My apologies. (I still have the original "why" question since your explanation still isn't one but that appears to be a deeper detail at this point.)

Comment: Seems like a timing issue in when the fds are are redirected and restored. `time` appears to output *after* the restoration of fds from the command it runs (the entire redirection set happens as part of the timed command I guess) whereas with the braces that forces the evaluation order to invert (by moving the redirection to the brace list instead of the timed command).

Comment: `>/dev/null 2>&1 time -p sleep 1` also captures/silences the output. Hm, no that's because it doesn't use the built-in that way.

Comment: First, this is an old and reasonably well known way to capture the output of `time` rather than the command it runs. Second, consider what `time` does: it runs a command and then after it completes, calculates the real, user, and sys times and prints them to stderr. If you look at the source code for `time`, it specifically prints to stderr and does so after the command it runs has already completed, so there's no timing issue here. The braces allow the fd redirection to be applied to the output of `time` rather than to the command `time` is running, as I essentially explained earlier.

Comment: I've never seen this before (well-known or not). And, yes, as I indicated the reason this works is because it changes the timing of when the shell performs the redirections. The time built-in behaves in a way different from other built-ins (e.g. `echo foo >/dev/null` works as expected, etc.). The redirections are not part of the command itself. I don't know if `time` considers them in its calculations or not. It is a timing issue even if it isn't a timing "problem". It makes some sense that `time` operate this way but is wasn't necessary for it to do so (and I can't find it in POSIX offhand).

Answer (score 2):

The bash builtin `time` outputs directly to your terminal, not to a stdio channel.
You'll need to use `/bin/time` which uses stderr:

```
$ time -p sleep 1  >/dev/null 2>&1
real 1.00
user 0.00
sys 0.00
$ /bin/time -p sleep 1
real 1.00
user 0.00
sys 0.00
$ /bin/time -p sleep 1  2>/dev/null
$
```

So:

```
$ command time -p sleep 1 2>&1 | awk -v limit=0.5 '$1 == "real" {exit ($2 <= limit)}'
$ echo $?
0
$ command time -p sleep 1 2>&1 | awk -v limit=1.5 '$1 == "real" {exit ($2 <= limit)}'
$ echo $?
1
```

and then

```
limit=1      # 1 second
if command time -p wget -O /dev/null -q http://site/file.iso |
   awk -v lmt=$limit '$1 == "real" {exit ($2 <= lmt)}'
then
    echo "FAST"
else
    echo "SLOW"
fi
```

Comment: So it looks like the built-in doesn't use the terminal directly it just undoes the redirections for the command *before* writing the output from `time` (which is why Steve Vinoski's answer works). (In bash 3 at least.)